# Setting API Keys with Gulp

Tags: gulp

I am trying to find a way to keep my API key more secure and set it when i run my demo. For example instead of running

```
gulp demo
```

I would like to be able to run

```
"gulp demo MY_API_KEY=testest"
```

I have looked through Gulp but i have not yet found a solution for this, can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set environment variables, you put it before the `gulp` command, like so:

`MY_API_KEY=123abc gulp demo`

Then in your gulpfile you can access the variable like this:

`var myApiKey = process.env.MY_API_KEY`